# Il sostantivo "manufatto" è il participio passato di un verbo irregolare?

Tags: verbs, word-choice, translation, english-comparison

Se la risposta fosse affermativa, vorrebbe dire che potrei utilizzarlo così,

> Questo strumento è stato sapientemente manufatto.

che mi sembrerebbe una traduzione quanto più vicina all'inglese seguente,

> This tool is skillfully crafted.

altrimenti no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, è solo un aggettivo (e, in altri contesti, un sostantivo). Come si può leggere sui dizionari (per esempio sul [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manufatto)), deriva dalle parole latine *manu factus*, cioè “fatto a mano”.

<sub>Un po' fuori tema: per la tua frase direi semplicemente qualcosa come “fatto/lavorato/realizzato (a mano) con (grande) abilità”.</sub>

Comment: Aggettivo *e* sostantivo (che, fra l'altro, è forse l'uso più frequente al giorno d'oggi).

Comment: Giusto, @egreg, integro.